# Is the back button the same as dispose() method?

Tags: flutter, dart, methods, callback, dispose

***flutter***

Is the back button the same as `dispose()` method ?
I know there's not much similarity, but I mean, when you hit the back button, does that free up memory from the tree of the page we left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you're talking about the Framework's `BackButton` widget, then eventually, why?

Because the framework's back button is just an abstraction of creating your own widget with an `IconButton` that calls `Navigator.maybePop(context);` when it is pressed.

To answer your question: yes, if the page is closed when `BackButton` is pressed, then yes it will release resources (it will call `dispose()` if your widget is a stateful widget).

Keep in mind that your still need to override the dispose() method and release any resource (if any) so that those resources are release when the back button is pressed.

To sum up::: `BackButton` simply calls `Navigator.maybePop(context);` and it will only release resources of your StatefulWidget IF you overrode it AND call `some_class.dispose()`.

Comment: This is the answer I absolutely want, thank you from the bottom of my heart MrMassango

Comment: so to increase knowledge only  the back button will get rid of the tree in case it was statefulwidget even if i did not override dispose() ?

Comment: No. It will only call the dispose() method of your stateful widget, so you still need to override the dispose () method and release all the resources you're using.

Answer (score 0):

No the back button doesn't replace the dispose function if you have controllers in a statefulwidget screen when state object is removed you will need to dispose it to avoid memory leaks.

[flutter](/questions/tagged/flutter)[dart](/questions/tagged/dart)[methods](/questions/tagged/methods)[callback](/questions/tagged/callback)[dispose](/questions/tagged/dispose)

Comment: so we use dispose()  controllers in statefulwidget only or there is others uses ? thanks

Comment: dispose can be used for other objects the controllers were just an example.

Here is a snippet from flutter documentation  "If a [State]'s [build] method depends on an object that can itself change state, for example a [ChangeNotifier] or [Stream], or some other object to which one can subscribe to receive notifications, then be sure to subscribe and unsubscribe properly in [initState], [didUpdateWidget], and [dispose]"